# Get the date between two date except Sunday

Tags: php

I have 2 dates and I need to get the dates between these two dates except Sunday.

Here is the code I have created so far.

```
<?php
$service_start_date = '2021-04-15';
$service_end_date = '2021-05-14';

$service_start_date = new DateTime($service_start_date);
                    $service_end_date = new DateTime($service_end_date);
                    $daterange = new DatePeriod($service_start_date, new DateInterval('P1D'), $service_end_date);
                    echo $daterange;
                    foreach($daterange as $date){
                        if(date("w", strtotime( $date)) != 0){
                        echo $date;
                        }
                        echo $date;
                    }

?>
```

This is the error I am getting:

> PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class DatePeriod could not be converted to string

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are getting that, because you are trying to _echo_ it … Use `var_dump` for making debug outputs.

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead of `echo`

Comment: @CBroe thanks man. Let me quickly check.

Comment: @halfer I will keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks Rocx `:=)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You work with DateTime and format or with date and strtotime. Mixing is bad. DatePeriod is not required. Solution with DateTime:

```
$service_start_date = '2021-04-15';
$service_end_date = '2021-05-14';

$endDate = date_create($service_end_date);
$startDate = date_create($service_start_date);
while($startDate < $endDate){
  if($startDate->format('w') != 0){
    echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
  }
  $startDate->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me try.